# Return a map iterator which is using a closure in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm learning some Rust solving the Matasano Crypto Challenges and am stuck with implementing the Ceasar cipher ("single-byte xor") as an iterator. **My function is supposed to look like this:**

```
fn ceaser_cipher_iter(data: &Vec<u8>, key :u8) -> SomeType {
    data.iter().map(move |&p| p^key)
}
```

Replacing `SomeType` with `()`, the compiler tells me what type it expects: `core::iter::Map<core::slice::Iter<'_, u8>, [closure src/main.rs:59:21: 59:31]>`. After some headbanging I found out I could use `std::slice::Iter<u8>` for `core::slice::Iter<'_, u8>`, which leaves the closure. As far as I understand, my naive experiment to use

```
fn ceaser_cipher_iter(data: &Vec<u8>, key :u8) -> Map<std::slice::Iter<u8>, fn(&u8)->u8 > {
    data.iter().map(move |&p| p^key)
}
```

cannot work, because Rust needs to know the exact closure type to allocate the memory for the closure (`key` has to be stored by being `move`d into the  closure). I've tried to follow [the advice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html#returning-closures) to use a `Box` instead:

```
fn ceaser_cipher_iter(data: &Vec<u8>, key :u8) -> Map<std::slice::Iter<u8>, Box<Fn(&u8)->u8> > {
    data.iter().map(Box::new(move |&p| p^key))
}
```

But afaict `map` does not support it:

```
src/main.rs:59:17: 59:47 error: the trait `core::ops::FnMut<(&u8,)>` is not implemented for the type `Box<for<'r> core::ops::Fn(&'r u8) -> u8>` [E0277]
src/main.rs:59     data.iter().map(Box::new(move |&p| p^key))
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:59:17: 59:47 error: the trait `core::ops::FnOnce<(&u8,)>` is not implemented for the type `Box<for<'r> core::ops::Fn(&'r u8) -> u8>` [E0277]
src/main.rs:59     data.iter().map(Box::new(move |&p| p^key))
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Is there a way to return a map iterator with a closure?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick is not to box the closure, but the iterator *as a whole*.

```rust
fn ceaser_cipher_iter<'a>(data: &'a Vec<u8>, key: u8) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item=u8> + 'a> {
    Box::new(data.iter().map(move |&p| p.key))
}
```

Note that because the iterator uses a borrow, I had to add lifetime annotations so that the code would pass borrow checking.