# Is there a way to let Rust infer the correct type for an associated type?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a trait which includes functions that return an iterator over some internal data, which can then be implemented by different structs. A minimal example is as follows:

```
trait WrapperTrait {
    type WrapperIterator: Iterator<Item=u32>;
    fn iter(&self) -> Self::WrapperIterator;
}
struct Wrapper {
    data: Vec<u32>
}
impl WrapperTrait for Wrapper {
    type WrapperIterator = ...;
    fn iter(&self) -> Self::WrapperIterator {
        return self.data.iter().map(|&x| x);
    }
}
```

However, the type for `WrapperIterator` is rather complex - from an error message (created via type mismatch) I find it to be:

```
std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, u32>, [closure@borrow.rs:45:37: 45:43]>
```

Is there a way to let Rust infer the correct type for `WrapperIterator`?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust would have the function body be just `self.data.iter().map(|&x| x)` — no `return`, no `;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to let Rust derive the correct type for `WrapperIterator`?

No. In fact, this is directly the opposite of what Rust does. You annotate function argument and return types, then the compiler can infer the types *inside* the method based on that.

Inferring top-level types from the body of the method leads to terrible error messages that occur far away from the location that caused them. Haskell learned this the hard way, and now advocates that all top-level functions have explicit type signatures. Rust chose to never go down that path. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31612025/155423); while it talks about lifetimes, many of the same points hold.

Your unasked question (how do I return this iterator) already has many duplicates:

- [Returning a closure from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25445761/155423)
- [Correct way to return an Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)
- [Return a map iterator which is using a closure in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31904842/155423)

Thank you for *not* asking yet another exact duplicate.

Comment: None of the linked "duplicates" appear to cover the case of implementing a trait.

Comment: The linked questions are about letting rust infer the return type of functions, which is not the same thing. The opinionated part of the response about Haskell is not quite appropriate in this context either. Actually rust is now working on implementing what the original poster wanted: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not yet possible in stable rust, but there is [a plan](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063) to introduce this feature. If you want to try the (currently unstable) feature, you can do so on rust nightly with `#![feature(min_type_alias_impl_trait)]`. You will have to add a type parameter to your trait :

```rust
#![feature(min_type_alias_impl_trait)]

trait WrapperTrait<'a> {
    type WrapperIterator: Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a;
    fn iter(&'a self) -> Self::WrapperIterator;
}

struct Wrapper {
    data: Vec<u32>,
}

impl<'a> WrapperTrait<'a> for Wrapper {
    type WrapperIterator = impl Iterator<Item = u32> + 'a;
    fn iter(&'a self) -> Self::WrapperIterator {
        self.data.iter().map(|&x| x)
    }
}
```

playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9434bcd32ea9c910fd0f9e329d17bd5

To do it without adding a lifetime parameter to the trait, one needs yet another unstable rust feature: Generic Associated Types.

```rust
#![feature(min_type_alias_impl_trait)]
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

trait WrapperTrait {
    type WrapperIterator<'a>: Iterator<Item = u32>;
    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::WrapperIterator<'a>;
}

struct Wrapper {
    data: Vec<u32>,
}

impl WrapperTrait for Wrapper {
    type WrapperIterator<'a> = impl Iterator<Item = u32>;
    fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::WrapperIterator<'a>{
        self.data.iter().map(|&x| x)
    }
}
```

playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=049c875b27a0e9e472d854e6218df267